# In Mechanize (Ruby), how to login then scrape?

Tags: ruby, forms, screen-scraping, mechanize

My aim: On ROR 3, get a PDF file from a site which requires you to login before you can download it

My method, using Mechanize:

Step 1: log in 
Step 2: since I'm logged in, get the PDF link

Thing is, when I debug and click on the link scraped, I'm redirected to the login page instead of getting the file

There are the 2 controls that I did on step 1:

```
(...)
search_results = form.submit
puts search_results.body
```

=> {"succes":true,"URL":"/sso/inscription/"}
Apparently the login succeed

```
puts agent.cookie_jar.jar
```

=> I could find the information about my session, si I guess that cookies are saved

Any hint about what I did wrong ?
(could be important: on the site, when you login into    "http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php", you are redirected to the home page (elwatan.com)

Below my code:

```
# step 1, login:
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_mail"
form.password = "my_pasword"
search_results = form.submit

# step 2, get the PDF:
@watan = {}
page.parser.xpath('//th/a').each do |link|
puts @watan[link.text.strip] = link['href']

end
```

Comment: Is your plan to keep asking the same question over and over?

Comment: My bad, I just added some new details in this question, maybe I could add it to the previous question (the fact is I did get the right answer on this post).
Sorry

Comment: pguardiario what? He needs a solution. There are two questions!

Comment: My contribution: https://github.com/juanccamachob94/mechanize/blob/master/login_and_protected_request.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `agent` variable retains the session and cookies.

So you first do your login, as you did, and then you write `agent.get(---your-pdf-link-here--)`.

In your example code is a small error: the result of the `submit` is in `search_results` and then you continue to use `page` to search for the links?

So in your case, I guess it should look like (untested of course) :

```
# step 1, login:
agent = Mechanize.new
agent.pluggable_parser.pdf = Mechanize::FileSaver

page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_mail"
form.password = "my_pasword"
page = form.submit

# step 2, get the PDF:
page.parser.xpath('//th/a').each do |link|
  agent.get link['href']
end
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately I get nothing when I debug (no more link); 
On the step 2, is it normal to parse the variable "page", while we set just before "page = form.submit", (and not the "page = agent.get(...)" anymore ?
Much appreciated !

Comment: The form submit will return you the new page. I presume you first need to log in, and then on that page, you can parse the links? Maybe you should get the first page again, after submitting the form. Not sure if mechanize can do javascript.

Comment: IT WORKED ! I have just changed in step 2 the "page" by "agent.get("http://elwatan.com/")" and it worked like a charm. thank you some much, it helped me a lot !

Answer (score 1):

`page` variable doesn't update after submit, link click, etc.

You need either work with page returned after submit:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")

form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_mail"
form.password = "my_pasword"
page = form.submit
```

Or manually get a new page:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get("http://elwatan.com/sso/inscription/inscription_payant.php")
form = page.form_with(:id => 'form-login-page')
form.login = "my_mail"
form.password = "my_pasword"
form.submit

page2 = agent.get('http://...')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer; unfortunately, it doesn't work, I'm still getting redirected to the login page!